# how would I get this Gemfile conflict resolved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Have used Rails a bit but am a bit confused as to this problem that I'm having.

I have two depdencies for xpath, one for 0.1.4 and one for 1.0

if I just run the following, it errors out:

```
Thu Feb 14$ rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb 
/Users/jt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find xpath (~> 1.0.0) amongst ...
```

but prepending bundle exec works.

```
$bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

I am curious how I could get this xpath issue resolved via my Gemfile. I thought this was the type of thing that bundler is supposed to handle. I know that `bundle exec` is supposed to be normal but I'd prefer to not have to use it.

What am I not undersanding and how do I resolve it?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Gemfile, you can force the version of a gem by appending to it the version number. If you require version up to 1.0.0, then you can write

```
gem "mygem", "~> 1.0.0"
```

You can get more info on how to manage gem versions in the [bundler site](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html).

Comment: so these are dependencies, could manage via Gemfile.lock but am a little confused as to why bundler can't handle this (fully acknowledge it probably can and I just don't know how)

Comment: @timpone bundler finds a set of versions that are all compatible with one another and recent, then locks them in the Gemfile.lock. If a new version comes but your Gemfile.lock was generated a long time ago, it won't go find the newest version.

Comment: right but shouldn't running `bundle update` force the Gemfile.lock to update?

Comment: @timpone that doesn't seem clear from the docs. Actually, they encourage you to indicate version numbers for each gem!

Comment: @timpone found an explanation here: http://gembundler.com/rationale.html , look for the "Updating a Dependency" section.

Comment: hmm.... I'll read through this but it seems like it's not handling things correctly. Essentitally, these are analagous to dynamic libraries in C. I know I'm doing something wrong :-(

Comment: @timpone I don't think you are doing anything wrong, it's just that bundler doesn't do what you *think* it should, and it's exactly because you have something else that depends on xpath (look at my link, they explain why they don't update in those circumstances)